# ThreeJS : Set object position to the controls target

Tags: three.js

Here. I'm looking to add the objects position to the controls target, i.e When I have a multiple objects I want the objects to rotate around the another object as the center. Where, when I try to do it the position of the object which assigned to the controls target bringing the object to the center of the scene. Here , I have no idea why it's reacting that way. Kindly help me out with the issue.

```
              var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3();
                boundingBox.setFromObject(data[0].object);
                var center = boundingBox.getCenter();
                camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(center.x, center.y, center.z));
                controls.target = center;
```

Comment: you don't need the:

camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(center.x, center.y, center.z));

since the controls.update() call will do that internally. You just set the target, and rather than controls.target = center, you may want controls.target.copy(center) though that is just a stylistic preference.

Comment: And actually yeah.. the controls.target =   might be your problem. Since now the vector might be shared with a termporary variable allocated inside three.


I'm guessing there is a warning in your console about how you are calling boundingBox.getCenter()  .. the newer versions of threejs require you to pass in a vector.. so boundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3() )

Comment: the reason for the warning is because allocating objects inside the library will eventually create garbage collection pressure and your app may eventually start to degrade performance after it has been running for a long time. It's a good practice to try to never call "new" inside your render loop, by preallocating all your objects once whenever possible.

Comment: Yes @manthrax I'm getting the warning ''THREE.Box3: .getCenter() target is now required''! Sure I will change my coding style, I have used .copy and removed the lookAt of the camera, But what happening is that when I place the object somewhere in the scene the object is directly moving to the center of the scene when the target values are triggered

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or a glitch?

Comment: Sure @manthrax 
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/field-longing-quiet
and also I have explained my problem clearly in https://discourse.threejs.org/t/while-updating-the-controls-target-to-a-object-position-its-moving-the-object-to-center/15887

Comment: so you want the controls to rotate around the target object, but you DONT want the camera to look at the target?

Comment: can you tell me what you're building because this problem is very abstract without some context.

Comment: if you want the camera to look at something other than the controls .target, you'll have to slam it right after the controls.update.. using camera.lookAt( someOtherPoint )

Comment: Yes sir @manthrax  I want the controls to rotate around the target object, but don't want to move the object to the center

Comment: @manthrax Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't understand enough to advise. Do yu have an example?

Comment: Yes @manthrax When I update the controls target to the object position it's moving the object to the center point. But I want the object to remain at the position and want to orbit (rotate) other objects to the new targeted object as the center. Please find the glitch where kindly, intersect to any object and move the cursor, the object will get moved to the center point, but i want the object to remain at the same position and to act as the target point https://glitch.com/edit/#!/field-longing-quiet?path=README.md%3A1%3A0